# Pygame, spawn second missile or alien didn't work

Tags: pygame, spawn

I'm a university student and I have a game project(we can choose whatever subject we want), which at the first went smooth but then I encountered some unexpected problems. I chose to create a simple version of raiden 2 (spaceship shooter game) but when it came down to spawn the missiles and the aliens it didn't work as expected. First of all when I press the space button the missile will be created and move from bottom to top, but when I hit It again It doesn't create a second or maybe It does but all I can see is the missile relocate right on top of the spaceship plus the speed increases(didn't intend to) instead i wanted to create a second while the first is moving. The same problem comes with the alien spaceship, the instance created and moved fine but when the time came for the second to spawn then the first just relocated at the new coordinates and its speed increased.Then for the alien I choose to create more with a for loop and then move them but again the speed have been increased and I could only see one. I have 4 more different classes of aliens that need to spawn but if I can't fix those problems I can't proceed. I also checked some tutorials and other questions here but when I tried the solutions it didn't work, I will keep searching but if someone find the error and could give me an example I would appreciate. Finally just to inform you I'm using images for the sprites etc. Here is the code:

Aliens:

```
class aliens(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, dw, dh, w, h):
    self.display_width = dw
    self.display_height = dh
    self.width = w
    self.height = h

    super().__init__()
```

First Alien:

```
class alienPrivate(aliens):
def __init__(self, dw, dh, w, h):
    super().__init__(dw, dh, w, h)

    self.image = alienPrivateImg
    self.rect = privateRect
    self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, display_width - w)
    self.rect.y = random.randrange(2*(-h), -h)
    self.weapon = 1
    self.damage = 5
    self.health = 10
    self.speed = 4

# Private moves top -> bottom    
def update(self):
    self.rect.y += self.speed
```

Missiles:

```
class Missiles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, dw, dh, wpn, pwlvl):
    super().__init__()

    self.weapon = wpn
    self.powerLevel = pwlvl
    self.setFire()

def setFire(self):
    if self.weapon == 1:
        if self.powerLevel == 1:
            self.image = bullets
            self.rect = bullet
    elif self.weapon == 2:
        if self.powerLevel == 1:
            self.image = frostLaserL1
            self.rect = frLaserL1
        elif self.powerLevel == 2:
            self.image = frostLaserL2
            self.rect = frLaserL2
        else:
            self.image = frostLaserL3
            self.rect = frLaserL3
    else:
        if self.powerLevel == 1:
            self.image = fireLaserL1
            self.rect = fLaserL1
        elif self.powerLevel == 2:
            self.image = fireLaserL2
            self.rect = fLaserL2
        else:
            self.image = fireLaserL3
            self.rect = fLaserL3

def update(self):
    self.rect.y -= 1
```

Missiles spawn:

```
missile = Missiles(display_width,display_height,weapon, powerLevel)
                missile.rect.x = hero.rect.x + 35
                missile.rect.y = hero.rect.y - 20
                all_sprites_list.add(missile)
                fire_list.add(missile)
```

Alien spawn:

```
for spawn in range(5):
                private = alienPrivate(display_width, display_height, 50, 88)
                all_sprites_list.add(private)
                alien_list.add(private)
```

The player class:

```
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, dw, dh, w, h):
    super().__init__()

    self.health = 100
    self.stamina = 100
    self.width = w
    self.height = h
    self.image = spaceshipImgBee
    self.rect = spaceshipRect
    self.rect.x = (dw / 2) - (self.width / 2)
    self.rect.y = dh - h
    self.weapon = 1
    self.powerLevel = 1


# Methods
def setPosx(self, x):
    self.rect.x = x

def setPosy(self, y):
    self.rect.y = y

def moveRigth(self, x):
    self.rect.x += x

def moveLeft(self, y):
    self.rect.y += y

def setWeapon(self, x):
    if self.weapon == x:
        if self.weapon == 1 and self.powerLevel == 1:
            self.damage += 10
            self.powerLevel += 1
        elif self.weapon == 1 and (self.powerLevel > 1 and self.powerLevel < 3):
            self.powerLevel += 1
        elif self.weapon == 2 and self.powerlevel < 3:
            self.damage += 15
            self.powerLevel += 1
        elif self.weapon == 3 and self.powerLevel < 3:
            self.damage += 25
            self.powerLevel += 1
    else:
        if x == 1:
            self.weapon = x
            self.damage = 10
            self.powerLevel = 1
        elif x == 2:
            self.weapon = x
            self.damage = 20
            self.powerLevel = 1
        elif x == 3:
            self.weapon = x
            self.damage = 50
            self.powerLevel +=1
```

And the rest of the game(a portion of it) including while loop:

```
import pygame
import random
import time

# Colors
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)

# Start Pygame
pygame.init()

# Window Size and Name
display_width = 700
display_height = 600
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Star Protector")

# Window refresh rate
fps = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Images
spaceshipImgBee = pygame.image.load('Hero_Spaceship_Bee_80x79.png')
spaceshipRect = spaceshipImgBee.get_rect()

alienPrivateImg = pygame.image.load('Alien_Private_50x88.png')
privateRect = alienPrivateImg.get_rect()

bullets = pygame.image.load('Bullets_10x20.png')
bullet = bullets.get_rect()

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
alien_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
fire_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

hero = player(display_width,display_height, 80, 79)
all_sprites_list.add(hero)
killed = False

x = 0
y = 0
i = 0
l = 0
score = 0
while not killed:
weapon = hero.weapon
powerLevel = hero.powerLevel
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        killed = True

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x = -10
            i = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x = 10
            i = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            y = -10
            i = 2
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            y = 10
            i = 2
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            if weapon == 1:
                missile = Missiles(display_width,display_height,weapon, powerLevel)
                missile.rect.x = hero.rect.x + 35
                missile.rect.y = hero.rect.y - 20
                all_sprites_list.add(missile)
                fire_list.add(missile)
            elif weapon == 2:
                if powerLevel == 1:
                    frlaser = Missiles(display_width, display_height, weapon, powerLevel)
                    frlaser.rect.x = (hero.rect.x / 2) - 7
                    all_sprites_list.add(frlaser)
                    fire_list.add(frlaser)

                elif powerLevel == 2:
                    frlaser = Missiles(display_width, display_height, weapon, powerLevel)
                    frlaser.rect.x = (hero.rect.x / 2) - 20
                    all_sprites_list.add(frlaser)
                    fire_list.add(frlaser)

                else: 
                    frlaser = Missiles(display_width, display_height, weapon, powerLevel)
                    frlaser.rect.x = (hero.rect.x / 2) - 40
                    all_sprites_list.add(frlaser)
                    fire_list.add(frlaser)
            else:
                if powerLevel == 1:
                    flaser = Missiles(display_width, display_height, weapon, powerLevel)
                    flaser.rect.x = (hero.rect.x / 2) -7
                    all_sprites_list.add(flaser)
                    fire_list.add(flaser)
                elif powerLevel == 2:
                    flaser = Missiles(display_width, display_height, weapon, powerLevel)
                    flaser.rect.x = (hero.rect.x / 2) -20
                    all_sprites_list.add(flaser)
                    fire_list.add(flaser)
                else:
                    flaser = Missiles(display_width, display_height, weapon, powerLevel)
                    flaser.rect.x = (hero.rect.x / 2) - 40
                    all_sprites_list.add(flaser)
                    fire_list.add(flaser)

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x = 0
            i = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            y = 0
            i = 2

#Move the spaceship with boundaries
if i == 1:
    hero.moveRigth(x)
elif i == 2:
    hero.moveLeft(y)

if hero.rect.x > display_width - hero.width:
    hero.setPosx(display_width - hero.width)
elif hero.rect.x < 0:
    hero.setPosx(0)
elif hero.rect.y < 0:
    hero.setPosy(0)
elif hero.rect.y > display_height - hero.height:
    hero.setPosy(display_height - hero.height)


#Background Color - Image
gameDisplay.blit(backgCosmos, (0 ,l))
#gameDisplay.fill(WHITE)

if score == 100:
    for spawn in range(5):
        private = alienPrivate(display_width, display_height, 50, 88)
        all_sprites_list.add(private)
        alien_list.add(private)

if l + 600 > 600:
    gameDisplay.blit(backgRepublic, (0 ,l -600))

l += 1

all_sprites_list.update()

#Print player - start the battle
all_sprites_list.draw(gameDisplay)

score += 1

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

As for the images I can't upload them(don't know why) but you can resize fast a random and test it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please turn the code snippets in your post into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and run without modifications.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what i had to do exactly so i tried to edit and add a small portion that maybe run so let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: Thanks, that's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was kind of interesting to fix, because it looks like you create and add the `missile`s to the groups correctly (you can see that by printing the sprite and the groups), but the problem is that you assign the same global variable `bullet` as the `self.rect` attributes to the missiles, and that means all missiles are placed at the same position. So when you update the rect's coordinates (`missile.rect.y = hero.rect.y - 20`), you affect all missile sprites because they share the same rect.

You should remove the `bullet` rect and just create the `self.rect` in the `__init__` method, so that each missile gets its own rect (the images can still be shared).

Also, better pass the `x` and `y` coordinates directly to the `__init__` method when you create the instance:

```
missile = Missiles(
    hero.rect.x+35, hero.rect.y-20,
    display_width,display_height,weapon, powerLevel)

class Missiles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, dw, dh, wpn, pwlvl):
        super().__init__()
        self.weapon = wpn
        self.powerLevel = pwlvl
        self.setFire()
        # You can pass the `x, y` coordinates as the `topleft`,
        # `center` or another argument.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        # Or set the coordinates afterwards.
        # self.rect.center = (x, y)

    def setFire(self):
        if self.weapon == 1:
            if self.powerLevel == 1:
                self.image = bullets
        elif self.weapon == 2:
            if self.powerLevel == 1:
                self.image = frostLaserL1
            elif self.powerLevel == 2:
                self.image = frostLaserL2
            else:
                self.image = frostLaserL3
        else:
            if self.powerLevel == 1:
                self.image = fireLaserL1
            elif self.powerLevel == 2:
                self.image = fireLaserL2
            else:
                self.image = fireLaserL3

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 1
```

You need to do the same for the alien ships:

```
class AlienPrivate(aliens):  # Use uppercase names for classes.
    def __init__(self, dw, dh, w, h):
        super().__init__(dw, dh, w, h)
        self.image = alienPrivateImg
        x = random.randrange(display_width-w)
        y = random.randrange(2*(-h), -h)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
```

Comment: You were right, I thought that maybe there was a problem with the image but I didn't know exactly what and how to fix it. Thank you, you saved me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You spawned the alien privates correctly with different instances, but need to do the same with Missiles.  `for i in range(number)` will give separate instances.  Otherwise, pygames sprite .add() will assume you're referencing the instance that already exists in the group.

Could you please put your game loop code `while True:` here?

In the meantime, check to see if passing the .update() to the individual sprites increases the speed.  Lastly, if a missile goes off the display, you can just .remove() it.

Comment: I will edit my question then and add the while loop but even if i spawned correctly the aliens, why after using  the all_sprites_list.draw(gameDisplay) I can only see my spaceship and only one of the 5 aliens image moving and not all of them?